# Blender Lamp (Surface and Light Strengths)

Tags: light

I would just like to ask why my lamp does not have any kind of surface properties as seen in a tutorial that I'm watching right now? I would like to know how to configure it because my lighting in the cycles renderer is pretty dim.[image]

Comment: I think that the surface properties are set on the materials directly, or on the object maybe. Your materials can diffuse and cast light, try to add some nodes to your material surface. It could looks better.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you mean by "surface properties", but try clicking the _Use Nodes_ button, and see if that is what you're missing.